# cannot access zzbgl class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbgl not found

Tags: android, android-studio, gmsmapview, gmsplacepicker

I want to use places api(new one).and when ever i sync gradle with the latest places api dependency it gives this error.Below is my code if any one can have a look and tell me if my versions are in correct and help me as it's been 3 days and i am not able to solve the problem.

I have already tried changing some versions of google play services and gms but didn't help.

this is my app level gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app.mapify"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.joooonho:selectableroundedimageview:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.maps:google-maps-services:0.2.11'
    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.25'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
//    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places-compat:1.1.0'
//    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.+'
    implementation 'com.firebase:geofire-android:2.1.1'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:2.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5+'
    implementation 'com.elyeproj.libraries:loaderviewlibrary:1.5.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    implementation 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'
    implementation 'com.victor:lib:1.0.4'
    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
//    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:12.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

this is my project level gradle file.

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Check and compare app.gradle file, current and when you run your project successfully.

Comment: i am not able to run the project successfully.it gives this error

Comment: I mean compare gradle file and versions, when you last ran your project without error. this may help you.

Comment: man,i dont have backup and now dont know which version to change

Comment: Ohh...sorry. Than it is difficult. Recently I have been facing similar issue. Solution hint is conflict between the version of firebase and gms-play-services dependency.

Comment: ok man thanks anyways